# How to use a reference to a FnOnce closure?

Tags: rust, closures

I have a function which needs to pass a closure argument recursively

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct TreeNode {
    val: i32,
    left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

pub fn pre_order<F>(root: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, f: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(i32) -> (),
{
    helper(&root, f);

    fn helper<F>(root: &Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce(i32),
    {
        match root {
            Some(node) => {
                f(node.borrow().val);
                helper(&node.borrow().left, f);
                helper(&node.borrow().right, f);
            }
            None => return,
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `f`
  --> src/lib.rs:23:45
   |
22 |                 f(node.borrow().val);
   |                 - value moved here
23 |                 helper(&node.borrow().left, f);
   |                                             ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `f` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `f`
  --> src/lib.rs:24:46
   |
23 |                 helper(&node.borrow().left, f);
   |                                             - value moved here
24 |                 helper(&node.borrow().right, f);
   |                                              ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `f` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

If I try changing type of `f` from `f: F` to `f: &F` I get the compiler error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:22:17
   |
22 |                 f(node.borrow().val);
   |                 ^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How can I get around this?

I am calling the function like this:

```
let mut node = TreeNode::new(15);
node.left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(9))));

let node_option = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(node)));
pre_order(node_option, |x| {
    println!("{:?}", x);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason `F ` needs be of type`FnOnce()` ?. If you change it to type `Fn()` and make `helper()` accept `&F`, it will work. `F:FnOnce()` makes the closure `F` move by value into the call and hence can be used just once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FnOnce` is the most most general function constraint. However, that means your code must work for all possible functions, including those that consume their environment. That's why it's called `FnOnce`: the only thing you know about it is that it can be called it *at least* once - but not necessarily more. Inside `pre_order` we can only assume what is true of *every possible* `F`: it can be called once.

If you change this to `Fn` or `FnMut`, to rule out closures that consume their environments,  you will be able to call it multiple times. `FnMut` is the next most general function trait, so it is preferred to accept that instead of `Fn`, to make sure you can accept the most functions:

```
pub fn pre_order<F>(root: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(i32),
{
    helper(&root, &mut f);

    fn helper<F>(root: &Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, f: &mut F)
    where
        F: FnMut(i32),
    {
        match root {
            Some(node) => {
                f(node.borrow().val);
                helper(&node.borrow().left, f);
                helper(&node.borrow().right, f);
            }
            None => return,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _you can call it at least once - but not necessarily more_ — Agree, I see  what you meant there :)  `F:FnOnce() + Copy`

Comment: @cotigao `FnOnce() + Copy` does not cover non-move closures that need to mutate their environment. Given that function types in OP's example do not have a return value, it's likely that he wants them to have side-effects.